# How can I do this in CSS without using a table?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

[image]

Normally, this would be incredibly easy with tables, but everyone says tables are bad now days.  Most of my web forms will be something like this:

[label]  [textbox]

[label]  [textbox]

[label]  [combobox] [textbox]

I just want everything to line up neatly.

*Edit: To clarify, I'm not using tables for the layout of my webforms.  That is done using CSS.  However, from some comments, it seems that tables are okay for lining up my controls.  I think that may be the best solution...

Comment: Have a look at the related questions list on the right - there are many similar questions.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using tables for tabular data. This is not tabular data. Tables are always wrong for page layout. What you are trying to do is equally, incredibly easy using CSS.

Comment: @Rob Then show us your _increadibly easy css_ for creating a form like this, please!

Comment: Meh.  Ignore the whiners.  Do what is incredibly easy and then spend your time working the incredibly hard part.

Comment: @Fatal, take your pick http://bit.ly/oWbIzf

Comment: I don't know if many would agree, but by the definition of tabular data here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa122605.htm -- a form with headings would qualify.

Comment: @Jim - That refers to the W3C but it's an old description. See the notes in the W3C link.

Comment: @Rob - I have a hard time parsing the meaning in the W3C spec -- does it explicitly state that forms w/ headings are not to be considered tabular data?

Comment: @Jim - Sorry, wrong link. From the W3C HTML spec:http://goo.gl/iGE2G  "Tables should not be used purely as a means to layout document content as this may present problems when rendering to non-visual media. Additionally, when used with graphics, these tables may force users to scroll horizontally to view a table designed on a system with a larger display. To minimize these problems, authors should use style sheets to control layout rather than tables."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've only tested in FF6 and Chrome, but here's one way to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/e7T3g/3/

Note that the first one is your image. Yes, this is not 100% perfect and will need to be tested and tweaked, but just wanted to show you that creating this layout with CSS is not a dream.

**(One reason) Why this is better than using tables:**

If you look at the markup, there's nothing that suggests layout at all, everything is semantic and uses classes. If one day you want to completely change how the layout looks, it's all in your CSS file. Using tables, you'll have to wade through tons of tedious `<tr>`s and `<td>`s in your HTML file *and* your CSS file to make a change. Likewise, if you want to make one small change, you aren't restricted by the table markup, which is very hard to work with.

The quick 'n dirty:

```
<form>
    <div class="address">
        <label>Address</label><input>
    </div>
    <div class="city">
        <label>City</label><input>
    </div>
    <div class="state">
        <label>State</label>
        <select>
            <option></option>
            <option>___</option>
            <option>___</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="zip">
        <label>Zip</label>
        <input>
    </div>
    <div class="archive">
        <label>Archive Location</label>
        <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
</form>
```

```
input {
    padding:3px;   
}
label:after {
    content:":";   
}
form {
    background:#888;
    padding:15px 25px 10px 15px;
    width:470px;
    float:left;
    font:900 13px serif;
}
.archive,
.address {
    float:left;
    width:100%;  
    margin-bottom:3px;
}

.archive label,
.city label,
.address label {
    width:100px;
    text-align:right;
    float:left;
}
.address input {
    width:360px;
}
.zip input {
    width:70px;   
}
.address,
.zip {
    float:right;   
}
.city,
.state {
    float:left;  
    margin-right:8px;
}
.archive {
    margin-top:5px;   
}
```

There's a million ways to do this layout, (and it's not a complete HTML fragment yet, we're missing some required attributes) and I'm sure I could come up with an better version, but I'll leave that as an exercise to you as you continue to learn CSS.

Comment: Would you call it easier than using tables or not? It's a serious question. In my opinion this is much harder to read and write than a table-based layout for this form. But maybe it's just because it's me. +1 though for the first one posting code here

Comment: @Fatal: Which part is hard to read or write for you, the HTML or CSS? Keep in mind, if we were doing a real website we'd have some sort of CSS framework set up for this, and also that this was just a quick hack-together. Remember that CSS is *for* styling HTML, while HTML is for describing what the content *is*.

Comment: IE8 is a bit off on the zip code input - but like I said - it's not a full solution, just a demo of what is possible. This layout is foolishly relying on some things like text width, but we could really make this awesome and IE-proof if we wanted to.

Comment: @Wesley Murch It's hard to get this HTML and CSS code together in mind. When I read a table-based layout I can imagine how it will look like without rendering it. This is much harder with the code you posted. These floats, clears, label:after, content:":" and so on... And I am sure it's harder to maintain as long as there is no framework doing the "hard work" for you.

Comment: @Fatal: CSS is tricky at first but the benefits are well worth it. When I say "framework", I mean we would have written a stylesheet that takes care of a lot of the little things in a general way (like default input padding, fonts, etc.) and this code could be smaller. I don't mean a grid system, but that could be a possibility, it's just not my personal taste. FWIW I know this code could be a lot tighter, I just wanted to crank something out quickly so OP could see the possibilities. Check out this site sometime to understand what I mean about CSS being awesome: http://www.csszengarden.com/

Comment: Yeah, the `label:after` was not necessary, I could have just put colons in the markup instead, but this was to demo some things you can do with just CSS.

Comment: Well styling your form elements with CSS is must have - at least for me. Even styling the table with CSS in a table-based layout. But the question was about table-based layout for a form or pure css layout. And for getting rid of the horrible parts (floats, clears etc.) you need something like a grid system. I am developing browser-based applications since years. I love CSS. But I learned to hate hardcore CSS, just for being state-of-the-art and someone else needs hours to understand what's going on. And in my opinion tables are here soooo much simpler and therefore better.

Comment: @Fatal - No, you don't need a grid system. The natural flow of the elements works pretty well all by itself. The benefits of CSS over tables overreach anything. Tables are a fixed, predefined element which is difficult to change once set. Tables themselves are styled with CSS in all browsers by default.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this tutorial:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/11/11/css-based-forms-modern-solutions/

You could use tables for forms but I prefer to use CSS because it is more maintainable and performant. Strictly speaking, tables should be used only for "tabular data" and this does not exactly describe form fields...

Comment: Depends on the definition of quote tabular data. http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa122605.htm
I don't think about.com is gospel, but 

"If you're going to have header fields at the top of columns of data or to the left of rows of data, then it is tabular and a table should be used." 

seems to apply to a form with headings.

Comment: Still a moot point: tables take from SEO and semantic HTML just to mention a couple of reasons for avoiding it. Performance is another and this becomes even more critical now that mobile access has surpassed desktop browser access...

Comment: Performance is a good reason, but if the data truly is "tabular data" then a table is perfectly semantic.

Comment: I'll grant you that... but I still would not opt to create forms with tables as it's just too messy :)

Answer (score 2):

Using the power of ems, p tags, and modular CSS:

#### HTML:

```
<form action="post" class="dummyForm" method="./" onsubmit="return false;">
    <fieldset class="formContainer">
        <legend class="formDescription">Form styling made easy!</legend>
        <p class="formElementWrapper">
            <label class="leftLabel formLabel" for="address">Address:&nbsp;</label>
            <input class="formElement orphanElement" id="address" name="address" type="text">
        </p>
        <p class="formElementWrapper">
            <label class="leftLabel formLabel" for="city">City:&nbsp;</label>
            <input class="cityInput formElement" id="city" name="city" type="text">
            <label class="formLabel" for="state">State:&nbsp;</label>
            <select class="formElement stateSelect" id="state" name="state">
                <option value="HI">HI</option>
            </select>
            <label class="formLabel" for="zip">Zip:&nbsp;</label>
            <input class="zipInput formElement" id="zip" name="zip "type="text">
        </p>
        <p class="formElementWrapper">
            <label class="leftLabel formLabel" for="archive">Archive Location:&nbsp;</label>
            <input class="formElement" id="archive" name="archive" type="checkbox">
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

#### CSS:

```
form.dummyForm
{
    width: 40em;
    background-color: #999999;
    font-family: Times New Roman, serif;
    font-size: .8em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
legend.formDescription, fieldset.formContainer, form.dummyForm
{
    border: none;
}
label.formLabel
{
    width: auto;
    padding-top: .1em;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
}
label.leftLabel
{
    width: 9em;
    text-align: right;
}
input.formElement, select.formElement, textarea.formElement
{
    margin-right: .5em;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    display: inline;
}
input.cityInput
{
    width: 9em;
}
select.stateSelect
{
    width: 4em;
}
input.zipInput
{
    width: 5em;
}
input.orphanElement, select.orphanElement, textarea.orphanElement
{
    width: 25em;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
}
p.formElementWrapper
{
    padding: .5em;
}
```

**Demo:** http://www.fortybelow.ca/hosted/misc/ieforms/

---

As a bonus, here's the form in various builds of IE:

IE 6:

[image: IE 6]

IE:Mac (an infamously terrible and dated browser):

[image: IE:Mac]

Comment: Nice work, this looks like something that could be used in production, mine was slammed together as fast as I could to quell the table proponents. This is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

Per your EDIT, no, tables still are not for layout just because it's a form. Your inputs are still not tabular data. You can wrap the whole thing in a div and style each input element as needed. See the Smashing link in the other answer for some examples.

Comment: Bleh. Looking at the Smashing article examples, most of them suck, and I'm leaving for a few hours. If no one else creates a fiddle for his example, I'll do one tonight.

Comment: When it is incredibly easy css why not posting some code snippets then? My experience is another: It is horrible doing things like this with pure CSS and it is less maintainable. But I'll change my mind when some really easy CSS comes out here for styling this form ...

Comment: Ok, but with tables it's about minutes to create something like that. Seems so there is more to do with CSS-styled form. Anyway, I stay tuned. :-)

Comment: @Fatal - Back sooner than expected but you're getting plenty of examples.